# How to adaptively sample a function with vector input and output?

Tags: python, optimization, vector, sample, sample-data

I'm trying to adaptively sample a function using `adaptive`.

Code:

```
import adaptive

def measure(setpoints: Union[float, np.ndarray]) -> Union[float, np.ndarray]:
    for setpoint in setpoints:
        measurement_schedule.add(setpoint)

    prepare_device(measurement_schedule)
    measurement_data = start_measurement()

    return measurement_data 

learner = adaptive.Learner1D(measure, bounds=(-1, 1))
runner = adaptive.Runner(learner, loss_goal=0.01)
```

where `measurement_data` has the same shape as `setpoints`. If the input and output are just scalars, it works fine with `adaptive`. However, `prepare_device()` takes quite a while, so I want to accelerate by using vector input/output to minimize the number of calls of `prepare_device()`. Multiprocessing is not feasible as there is only one device. Any idea how to do this by `adaptive`, or is there any other Python package that can do this?

I see that `adaptive` natively supports multiprocessing, so from the aspect of algorithm it should be possible to do this in theory.